# Arrow keys of laptop are constantly activating themselves

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

My main keyboard of my laptop has been very frustrating. When I first turn on my laptop the arrow keys on the keyboard keep activating themselves consecutively, so it produces some unusual sound that scares you.

Then a window opens that makes me choose Windows 7. After that, it's making me choose whether to start normally, safe mode, etc and after choosing one of that, the sound comes back and takes forever to wait.

What can I do?

Comment: Seems to me like an hardware issue because it shows up even before the Windows 7 has had its boot. Anyway, if you are conversant working with hardware, all that you need will be your laptop manual and a simple screwdriver - to disconnect your built-in keyboard. Once you disconnect your keyboard, connect an external USB keyboard and see if the problem persists...

Comment: thanks,I'll try it.. its very frustrating it's almost like im killing the f*cking arrow keys of my main keyboard and then that music and creepy sound stop but whenever i search a web,sometimes it occurs and i kept killing it so now the main arrow keys of my keyboard are now bald xD anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like a hardware problem. If you still have warranty for the laptop, I would exchange it.

Go to the system settings and open the device manager. Find keyboard in the list of devices and expand it. Right-click on the internal keyboard and click Disable. If there is no Disable option, click Uninstall.

If that does not work, the keyboard can also be taken out.